# Why do I get additional API calls when performing single request?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

My Application is a private app and the UI is deployed in AWS cloudfront and the backend API is deployed as lambda function.

In latest versions of the web browsers, when i make a call browser is generation 2 more additional calls which confuse me and one of them is failing.

Below image shows that there are 2 different api calls, But for each of them 2 more additional call are generated.
[image]

In the backend we have an additional edge lambda which is attaching below headers for the api calls.
[image]

What am I missing here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are they options requests?

Comment: Yes. The second one. In the pic it shows the third one

Comment: Seems to me that there are 3 requests. The second call, if it's an OPTION method, is most likely a CORS request and you shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Yes. Any reason why do i get the third request?

Comment: Could you please share more code? with this amount we can not find the root cause